# Difference between types of database projects in Visual Studio

Tags: database, visual-studio-2008

In Visual Studio 2008 I have 2 types of database projects:

- C# -> Database -> SQL Server Project
- Other project Types -> Database -> Database Project

What is the difference between these 2? Is there any reason to use one over ther other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- SQL Server projects in Visual Studio
  assist in the creation of stored
  procedures, triggers, aggregates,
  user-defined functions, and
  user-defined types using .NET
  Framework languages such as Visual
  Basic, Visual C#, and Visual C++.
- The database project is a special
  type of Visual Studio.NET project.
  Its purpose is to create and manage
  SQL database scripts. If you're
  developing database applications with
  Visual Studio.NET, you will want to
  know about the tools available for
  making your work with databases
  easier and faster.